# How can I solve the following integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve the following integral:

```
Integrate[E^(-1.5*a^2-3.5*a*\[Beta]r-2.02*\[Beta]r^2)*(0.8+0.8*E^(7*a*\[Beta]r))*
(1+Log[1/(1+E^(7*a*\[Beta]r))]/((1+E^(7*a*\[Beta]r))*Log[2])+
((1-1/(1+E^(7*a*\[Beta]r)))*Log[1-1/(1+E^(7*a*\[Beta]r))])/Log[2]),
 {\[Beta]r,\[Beta]c,Infinity}]
```

But unfortunately Mathematica in my laptop cannot solve it. Is there any way to solve this integral ?

Comment: To do numerical integrations, then all parameters in the integrand need to have numerical values. (the `a` and `BetaC` in your case) then `NIntegrate` works.

Comment: I want to get the result according to "BetaC" and "a", because I have to plot in 3D the result using these two variables ( The "a" varies between 0 and 1.5 and The "BetaC" varies between 0 and 2 )

Comment: If you want symbolic anti-derivatives, there is none. You said in your question "what is the most innocent approximation" and you also added ""numerical integration" as a tag. You can do numerical integration for different `a` and `betas`. It was very fast. Not every integral can be solved analytically.

Comment: I can not add an interval of variation of "a" and "betaC" in the integral !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate), and restrict the arguments to numeric quantities:

```
res[a_?NumericQ, βc_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
    E^(-1.5 * a^2 - 3.5 * a * βr - 2.02 * βr^2)*
    (0.8 + 0.8 * E^(7 * a * βr))*
    (1+Log[1/(1+E^(7*a*βr))]/((1+E^(7*a*βr))*Log[2])+((1-1/(1+E^(7*a*βr)))*Log[1-1/(1+E^(7*a*βr))])/Log[2]),

    {βr,βc,Infinity}
]

Plot3D[res[a, βc], {a, 0, 1.5}, {βc, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Carl Woll, it is very interesting,